# Is ADO.NET 4 the same as Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

Is ADO.NET 4 the same as Entity Framework 4? I'm looking for a book on Entitry Framework and saw this [Title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735638888). Not sure if what I'm looking for though.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not. ***[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx)*** is an ***[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)*** that has been built on the top of [***ADO.NET***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx). Although the book you've mentioned has a small chapter on EF, but its main focus is on ADO.Net basis and its core classes. 

If you are looking for a book on EF, then don't miss this GREAT book, it's all you need:



[image]

Comment: +1, and check this [post](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/book/programming-entity-framework-e-book-for-9-99-today-only/) by the author.  The discount code was still working today :)

Comment: No problem and Happy Reading :)

Answer (score 2):

The official name for "Entity Framework" is "Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework".

A book on ADO.NET 4 should include information about Entity Framework 4 but you might be better off with a book focused solely on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how MSDN defines the relationship between them:

> The Entity Framework is a set of
>   technologies **in** ADO.NET that
>   support the development of
>   data-oriented software applications.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx)